# How do I add an extra attribute for classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am playing around with classes in Python and do not understand how to add extra 'attributes'. For example my simple code that I have come up with below:

```
class Bird():

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age=age
    def birdsit(self):
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is sitting')
    def birdfly(self):
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is flying')
    def birdwalk(self):
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is walking')
   

    
myBird=Bird('Blue',4)

print(myBird.name)
myBird.birdsit()
myBird.birdfly()
myBird.birdwalk()
```

I am trying to simply add an attribute eg. the Type or Gender of the bird. I am self studying and the textbook I am using is so confusing and overwhelming and I can't really find a clear explanation.

Comment: You can add a new attribute like `myBird.gender = 'non-binary'`

Comment: You can add them just like the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. It's the same syntax for setting name or age. Also, watch out for your indents in the original post - the methods (i.e. def birdsit, def birdfly) all need to be indented once more than the class.

```
class Bird():

    def __init__(self, name, age, type, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.type = type
        self.gender= gender

    def birdsit(self):
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is sitting')


    def birdfly(self):
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is flying')


    def birdwalk(self):
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is walking')


myBird = Bird('Blue', 4, 'swallow', 'do birds have genders?')

print(myBird.name, myBird.gender, myBird.type)
myBird.birdsit()
myBird.birdfly()
myBird.birdwalk()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see I was making a silly error of not including the argument correctly. Thank you for the assistance friend.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly are you trying to add?  You already know how to create a new data attribute: simply assign to it.  For instance, if you want a `movement` attribute for your bird, just do this:

```
    def birdsit(self):
        self.movement = "sit"
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is sitting')
    def birdfly(self):
        self.movement = "fly"
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is flying')
    def birdwalk(self):
        self.movement = "walk"
        print(self.name + ' is a bird that is walking')
```

If the attribute doesn't exist, then it's created when you first hit one of these assignments.  If it already exists, the assignment merely changes its value.

In this respect, it's just like a regular Python variable.

Comment: I was trying to add a new description. Apologies if my code/phrasing of the question is slightly unclear, I'm new to classes and trying to grasp the concepts so its my own 'baby-step' code to understanding it the way the textbook is teaching me. Thank you kindly for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes can be defined in the **init**() function which is automatically run when an instance of a class is created. To add a species attribute you can add it in the init function.

```
def __init__(self, name, age, species):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.species = species
```

Comment: This is overly restrictive: you can create an instance attribute in any method, not merely `__init__`.

Comment: Poster is a novice and is learning from a textbook. Kept it simple for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm still learning the concept of it. In the textbook they are only using __init__ for now so thank you for the consideration.